# AS3/AIR mobile app dynamic text size depending on length

Tags: actionscript-3

I am developing an app in AS3 and AIR for iOS and Android that has a lot of labels and wondering if anyone knows what the best method of decreasing the size of the font if the label text length is too long.

I basically want the text in a label to always fit regardless of the length.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished in a variety of ways.

You could call a `fitLabel()` passing the text field and a bounding box:

```
fitLabel(textField, new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight));
```

One approach would be scaling the text field to the bounds:

```
protected function fitLabel(textField:TextField, bounds:Rectangle):void
{
    var metrics:TextLineMetrics = textField.getLineMetrics(0);
    var ratio:Number = Math.min(bounds.width / metrics.width,
                                bounds.height / metrics.height);

    textField.scaleX = ratio;
    textField.scaleY = ratio;
}
```

Another approach would be implementing an algorithm that adjusts font size accounting for dpi:

```
protected var dpi:uint = 72;

protected function fitLabel(textField:TextField, bounds:Rectangle):void
{
    var metrics:TextLineMetrics = textField.getLineMetrics(0);

    var format:TextFormat = textField.getTextFormat();
    format.size = (stage.stageWidth / dpi) * 13;

    textField.setTextFormat(format);
    textField.width = bounds.width;
    textField.height = bounds.height;
}
```

Yet another approach would be iterating through a `while` loop increasing font size each pass until the maximum width reaches the bounds.

[Example SWF](http://jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/examples/dynamic-text-size/):

> [image: hello-world]